# WPF take screenshot of application including hidden content

Tags: wpf, screenshot

Under the category "limitations of the technology":

I have received the requirement to have a screenshot button in my application that will take a screenshot and launch a printer dialog. Fair enough. My code achieves that. I simply take my window, and use a RenderTargetBitmap to render the window.

However, the requirement now states that it should include all content that is hidden behind scrollbars. Meaning, that **in the screenshot** the application should look "stretched" in order to eliminate scrollbars, and show all data. For instance in case there is a large list or datagrid, all the data should be visible.

Keeping in mind that WPF might be virtualizing and not rendering things that are not in view, is there any way I can achieve this requirement? Is there a possibility of rendering the visual tree to a seperate infinite space and taking a screenshot there? Something else?

**In response to comments:**

The screenshot button is on an outer shell that only holds the menu. Inside this shell any of 800+ views can be hosted. These views could contain datagrids, lists, large forms consisting of textboxes... anything. There is no way to tell what is 'inside' without walking the visual tree.

The functionality requested is similar to printing a webpage in your browser to PDF. It will also give you the entire DOM instead of just what you see in the limited view of the browser.

Comment: Is it always a datagrid ?

Comment: Instead of taking screenshot you can directly print your datagrid or listview or listbox by measuring its size with window size and print with printvisual

Comment: @FelixD. No, this can be anything. We are talking an application of 800+ views. This could be datagrids, listviews, itemscontrols, large forms consisting of textboxes... The screenshot button is on the surrounding shell. The view hosted in the shell can be anything

Comment: @UsmanAli It is not just datagrids. It should work for no matter what kind of screen or control is within the outer shell of the application. The shell is a host, that can host any kind of view. The shell has no information on which kind of view or control is within (unless it starts walking the visual tree)

Comment: What about a Viewbox, could that achieve what you're targeting?

Comment: @DarkTemplar I'm not sure how. AFAIK a viewbox only rescales everything, meaning that the 'amount' of content will remain the same. But I'll experiment with it.

Comment: @Bjorn Why not selling this as a print preview feature? So you could hide the specific elements.

Comment: What does requirement says when there are 2000 or more records are present on the screen? How is user going to print that and is it feasible? Also the records that are not visible are they really necessary?! If user can't see them what is the point in including them. They are in the database and are out of scope. You need to question those reqs cause they are nothing more than botched up together to get irrelevant info and cover whoever came up with them.

Comment: @XAMlMAX: It will be probably "print to pdf" 50 pages in that case. However, we don't get that many results at once since most of our views are paginated. Still, the view can be a couple of times "taller" than a standard 1920x1200 screen with standard scaling.

Answer (score 1):

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <Button
        x:Name="btnPrint"
        Width="50"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Click="BtnPrint_Click"
        Content="Print" />
    <ScrollViewer Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid x:Name="toPrint">
           <!--your code goes here-->
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pdialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            System.Windows.Size pageSize = new System.Windows.Size { Height = pdialog.PrintableAreaHeight, Width = pdialog.PrintableAreaWidth };
            toPrint.Measure(pageSize);
            toPrint.UpdateLayout();
            pdialog.PrintVisual(toPrint, "Print");

        }
    }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will still limit the size of the result to one page, seeing as you are using PrintableArea in your measure.

Comment: it will measure the size inside ScrollViewer

Comment: For this simple example it works, but not for the real application. Simply because the scrollviewer can be many levels down in the visual tree, or it could be multiple scrollviewers, datagrids... or maybe there are hardcoded MaxHeights... I'm going to file this requirement under 'impossible'. Thanks for the suggestion though