# How to take a screenshot of a Full Size window in C# (Scrolling window)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi I am trying to create an application in C#.net that captures the screenshot of the current active including the area that has to be scrolled using scroll bars.I found the following code to take screenshot. TO be very clear I want the code to take screenshot of the active window including the area that is not displayed and is only revealed by using scroll bars. Any help is greatly appreciated.Thank you

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6n6t.png)

```
        public static void PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        try
        {

            RECT rc;
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

            PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);

            gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
            gfxBmp.Dispose();



            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            if (!AllOneColor(bmp))
            {
                bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\Dhibi\Desktop\" + guid + ".Png", ImageFormat.Png);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54748765/5378935

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF take screenshot of application including hidden content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747801/wpf-take-screenshot-of-application-including-hidden-content)

Comment: Edit the tag for this question.

Comment: What is the easiest way in C# to take a " screenshot " of a complete scrolling Window?

Comment: I don't have any immediate answer to this. I imagine your constraint here will be methods on DeviceContext.  I think there might be support for this with [dotnetframework.org - DeviceContext2](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/Misc/GDI/DeviceContext2@cs/6/DeviceContext2@cs) (this fairly awful looking)

Comment: here's a better link, as GDI in Windows.Form.Internal [DeviceContext2.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/misc/GDI/DeviceContext2.cs)